# iphone simulator MapView does not load, instead shows grey tiles

Tags: iphone, xcode4.3

i am using xcode 4.3.3.

I am trying a sample mapview app. In which i just have 1 view controller with 1 mapview. I want to show a particular location whose coordiates i have set in my code. When i run without setting a region my map shows default America region, but when i set my region with coordinates it shows only grey tiles and nothing. Below is my code.

```
    #import "BranchViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "Annotation.h"

@interface BranchViewController ()

@end

#define CBB_LATITUDE    26.2167;
#define CBB_LONGITUDE   50.5833;

#define THE_SPAN        0.01f;

@implementation BranchViewController
@synthesize myMapView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"BranchViewController - viewDidLoad()");
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // CBB REGION
    MKCoordinateRegion cbbRegion;

    // CBB LATITUDE N LONGITUDE
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = CBB_LATITUDE;
    center.longitude = CBB_LONGITUDE;

    // CBB SPAN
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    cbbRegion.center = center;
    cbbRegion.span = span;

    // SETTING MAPVIEW
    [self.myMapView setRegion:cbbRegion animated:NO];
    [self.myMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    //[self.myMapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    self.myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;





}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setMyMapView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: map view taken with xib? if yes make sure you have linked the connection and implemented the mapview delegate properly.

Comment: yes it is a UIViewController in which there is a connection for mapview. But can u pls tell me where to check if the mapview delegates are implemented correctly ?. i dont remember i implemented any delegate as i just followed one tutorial.

Comment: it is resolved now. my 1st mistake was i did not set map.delegate=self. 2nd mistake was that my internet connection was not working and this i figured by implementing mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError method. Thanks... D-eptdeveloper

Answer (score 0):

it is resolved now. my 1st mistake was i did not set map.delegate=self. 2nd mistake was that my internet connection was not working and this i figured by implementing mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError method. Thanks... D-eptdeveloper